# How to define a typedef which is dependent on a template argument's typedef

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I'd like to make a `typedef` which is dependent on the existence of a `typedef` in a template argument:

```
struct foo
{
    using MyType = int;
};

template <typename T = foo>
struct bar
{
    // Pseudo code
    #if T::MyType is defined
        using MyType = T::MyType;
    #else
        using MyType = double;
    #endif
};
```

Is there a way to get it to work using `std::conditional` or something else in C++14?

Comment: Use [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is, with a bit of sfinae.

```
template<class, typename Fallback, typename = void>
struct type_or_default {
    using type = Fallback;
};

template<class C, typename F>
struct type_or_default<C, F, std::void_t<typename C::type>> {
    using type = typename C::type;
};
```

This uses the standard convention where template meta-functions expose a member name `type`, but you can adapt it for your own naming needs. The only non-C++14 bit here is `std::void_t`, but an equivalent thing can be implemented in C++14 (it just can't be put into namespace `std`). You use it in your class like this:

```
template <typename T = foo>
struct bar
{
    using type = typename type_or_default<T, double>::type;
};
```

What happens here is that the compiler does its pattern matching when choosing a template specialization. If the class `C` has a member `type`, then the partial specialization we provided will be considered more specialized, and as such chosen. Otherwise (if substitution fails when checking the specialization), the primary template is always there to fall back to.

[Live program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/badc3907f3d44114) to tinker with.

Comment: Congrats on the 100k by the way

Comment: @SombreroChicken - Thank you very much! Now I just need to decide if it was worth the price, chiefly my sanity

Comment: @SombreroChicken - I only got deep into C++ because someone was wrong on SO once. Then just rolled with it.

Comment: Hmm, could've been me

Comment: @StoryTeller a belated question, why do we need the `typename = void` as the third template argument in the first function?

Comment: @Shmoopy - The third argument gives us a context for further substitution. First a compiler figures out the template arguments. Those are `foo`, `double` and `void`. Then it checks if there is a specialization it can substitute into that matches those arguments. During said substitution the existance of `type` is checked. And if it exists, `void_t` is a well formed alias to `void` and so our specialization matches the third argument.

Answer (score 1):

My five cents to this question.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename DefaultType>
struct CalculateMyType {
    template <typename C>
    static typename C::MyType test(typename C::MyType*);

    template <typename>
    static DefaultType test(...);
    typedef decltype(test<T>(nullptr)) MyType;
};


struct foo
{
    using MyType = int;
};


template <typename T = foo>
struct bar
{
    using MyType = typename CalculateMyType<T, double>::MyType;
};


struct baz
{
};

struct quux
{
    using MyType = float;
};


#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename>
struct TypeToStr;

template<> struct TypeToStr<double> { const char * name = "double"; };
template<> struct TypeToStr<float> { const char * name = "float"; };
template<> struct TypeToStr<int> { const char * name = "int"; };

int main() {

    std::cout << "bar<foo>::MyType = " << TypeToStr<bar<foo>::MyType>().name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "bar<baz>::MyType = " << TypeToStr<bar<baz>::MyType>().name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "bar<quux>::MyType = " << TypeToStr<bar<quux>::MyType>().name << std::endl;
}
```

[Live program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a84544d04e7614ef)